# Javascript variable names in loop

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a function that creates 6 html input boxes to store my score values, 1 of the boxes being the total score.

```
var hole1 = prompt("Enter Hole 1 score:");
var hole2 = prompt("Enter Hole 2 score:");
var hole3 = prompt("Enter Hole 3 score:");
var hole4 = prompt("Enter Hole 4 score:");
var hole5 = prompt("Enter Hole 5 score:");
```

The whole function of addScore():

```
function addScore() {

            var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
            var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
            var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
            numi.value = num;

            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
            newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);

            // Prompts user for their score
            var hole1 = prompt("Enter Hole 1 score:");
            var hole2 = prompt("Enter Hole 2 score:");
            var hole3 = prompt("Enter Hole 3 score:");
            var hole4 = prompt("Enter Hole 4 score:");
            var hole5 = prompt("Enter Hole 5 score:");

            // Make the boxes for index.html to be displayed
            var makeScoreBoxes ='<input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 1" id="hole1" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 2" id="hole2" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 3" id="hole3" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 4" id="hole4" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 5" id="hole5" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Total Score" id="totalScore" />'
            newdiv.innerHTML = makeScoreBoxes;
            ni.appendChild(newdiv);

            // Adds up all scores entered via hole 
            totalScore = parseInt(parseFloat(hole1) +
                                                    parseFloat(hole2) +
                                                    parseFloat(hole3) +
                                                    parseFloat(hole4) +
                                                    parseFloat(hole5));

            // Places output of each data value from totalScore into input boxes in index.html
            addTotal = document.getElementById('totalScore').value=totalScore;
            addhole1 = document.getElementById('hole1').value=hole1; // takes prompt number entered in all hole* variables
            addhole2 = document.getElementById('hole2').value=hole2;
            addhole3 = document.getElementById('hole3').value=hole3;
            addhole4 = document.getElementById('hole4').value=hole4;
            addhole5 = document.getElementById('hole5').value=hole5;

            } // Adds up all scores entered via hole 
            totalScore = parseInt(parseFloat(hole1) +
                                    parseFloat(hole2) +
                                    parseFloat(hole3) +
                                    parseFloat(hole4) +
                                    parseFloat(hole5));
```

And it is called here in index.html:

```
<center><p><a href="javascript:;" onclick="addScore();"><h1>Add score</h1></a></p>
```

How do I generate unique variable names for the hole prompt values ( hole1, hole2, hole3, hole4, etc) and html input box ( hole1, hole2, hole3,) values?

Comment: You want to learn about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) and [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Here's a general rule that every programmer should learn immediately after they write their first 'hello world' program. If you find yourself writing `var1`, `var2`, etc. you should probably using arrays (or something similar) instead.

Comment: This "question" appears to be off-topic on StackOverflow because it does not pose an actual question. It doesn't even ask for anything.

Comment: Your wording needs to be clarified a little bit. Exactly what you're you're asking for is unclear. Also, @p.s.w.g has a great suggestion - make sure you're using the appropriate data structure for your goal.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I'm asking how to create unique names for the html box variables, as well as the score variable names.

Comment: OK, thank you. However, as we already told you, you shouldn't :-)

Comment: So arrays is the way to go then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what can be done with arrays:

```
var holes = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    holes.push(prompt("Enter Hole " + i + " score:"));
}

var totalScore = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < holes.length; i++) {
    totalScore += parseInt(holes[i], 10);
}

alert("total score: " + totalScore);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EhpPZ/

Comment: My last question is, how do I take in of the 5 input prompts and put them inside of the 5 html boxes.